# iOS - Video looping not working on iphone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using MPMoviePlayer to play video in my iPhone application.

I want play video in loop means wants to play single video repeatedly.

I am using following code to repeat the video:

```
MoviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

It is working properly on Simulator and higher phone But it is **not working properly on iPhone 4**.

It is not repeating the video on iPhone 4 Device

Is there any specific reason for that? is there any solution for that?

My iPhone is **iPhone 4 with updated iOS 7**

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest to check the device console for suspicious entries, try a short low-res video, submit bug-report if nothing helps.

Comment: The video is very small with resolution 320X240 and size is in KB's only. Its length is about 30 sec.

Comment: Try 160x120 ? You can also try one of the other supported video formats to see if it helps but it won't be a real fix anyway. Either keep trying to find the reason yourself or contact Apple support if you can provide them a case to reproduce. Unfortunately there isn't much you can do.

Comment: I got solution below. But Thank you @A-Live for your suggestions.

Comment: How did you install iOS 8 on iPhone 4?

Comment: Oops !!! It is By Mistake. Thanks for correction @Omer. The OS is iOS 7 Updated version actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solution I have implemented:

I have used `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` this Notification

Added following notification to Movie Player

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinishedFromSetUnderway:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:MoviePlayer];
```

Notification Method:

```
-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinishedFromSetUnderway:(NSNotification *)dict{

    if (dict.object == MoviePlayer) {
        NSInteger reason = [[dict.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [MoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            [MoviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Done !!! It is working properly now ... :)